# Combine 2 Netty servers into a single one

Tags: netty

I have one Netty server ( basically taken from the Netty example ObjectEchoServer ) that is running in an OSGi plugin. The server is bound to port 51515 and is working just the way it should. I understand the basic concept so far.

Now I need too add some kind of "embedded Http" server to my pluging. I have zaken the HTTPServer from the Netty examples and modified it so it fulfills my needs. The server is bound to a seperate port 51516.

I need some help, bringing the two servers together. Both serverse only differ in their handlers.

The ObjectEcho

```
extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Object>
```

while the HTTPServer

```
extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<FullHttpRequest>
```

Is it possible to have only one handler that can be used for both servers?

What I want to achieve is that both servers only use one port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still have 2 differents ports, you can through Java heritage build your own "business" Handler and then adding at first the protocol handler (echo one, and http one) and in second your own business handler.

Of course everything depends on the possible object to pass to this business handler, since it has to be the same, whatever the echo or http handlers do at first time.

By the way, it is a good practice to separate "protocol" from "business" handlers...

**Update response:**

In your pipeline, for both servers (2 ports), add at first the "protocol" driver using an extension of `ChannelDuplexHandler` instead of `SimpleChannelInboundHandler`, and then add your own business handler (based on `SimpleChannelInboundHandler`).

From the protocol business, forward to inbound business handler the object as desired and return the object in order to the `ChannelDuplexHandler` transform back to the protocol.

This way, you separate the protocol (codec) and the business.

Even if it is not exactly what you want, you can have a look at example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/spdy/client which show how to do it (client side, but server side is exactly the same principle).

**Second update:**

To have only one port, it is more complicated since you will then need to hace a previous `ChannelDuplexHandler` that will analyze the first bytes to indentify the correct type of protocol. Then you can had dynamically to the pipeline the necessary handlers (protocol and business).

So at first, only one handler will be in your pipeline, the one that decides which protocol has to be used.

Note however that could be difficult. Except if you have an explicit difference in the first bytes that ensure the protocol, you might have no real solution, except having two ports, since the program must be deterministic.

Comment: For the echo, all objects are POJO, containing Strings that are used by the EchoHandler to trigger requests on the server. The server sends back Strings.

Comment: The HTTP part received HTTPRequest and returns an HTML page build from log ( textfiles )

Comment: Can you post some pseudo code. This would give me a better understanding

Comment: In your pipeline, for both servers (2 ports), add at first the "protocol" driver)

Comment: The goal is to have only one port.

Comment: I try to improve my answer, hoping it helps you in the right direction...